# Sending multiple 5mb binary files over WS vs Http

Tags: http, networking, websocket, http2

1. Does sending large files over a websocket "block" websocket for other messages while the large files are being sent?
2. Does sending the files via independent Http requests while the other messages continue to be sent over WS have any distinct advantage "in keeping the WS unblocked"?

Assume 1 network card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In case of WebSocket over HTTP/1.1, yes, the upload of a large file (in the form of a large WebSocket message) blocks the WebSocket connection.
   In case of [WebSocket over HTTP/2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8441) (if supported by both the client and server), one HTTP/2 stream will upload the large file, and another HTTP/2 stream is be used to carry WebSocket messages. In this case, the problem becomes the HTTP/2 flow control window, which may be exhausted by the large upload stream, leaving the WebSocket message stream stalled (so that messages are queued and delayed). Unfortunately, the details  of this queueing/delay depend on the client and on the server implementations, so you have to try.
   Typically implementations do a good job at interleaving streams, so rarely the possible stalls are a problem.
   For WebSocket over HTTP/1.1, if you open multiple WebSocket connections, you may be able to send files and messages in parallel, using `N` WebSocket connections for the files, and `1` WebSocket connection for the messages, for example.
   Some non-browser clients allow you to open multiple HTTP/2 connections to the same domain, so again you will have the chance to send files and messages in parallel. However, to my knowledge, browsers do not allow more than 1 HTTP/2 connection to the same domain, so the parallelism is there, but constrained by the HTTP/2 flow control window.
2. Not sure what you mean by "keeping the WS unblocked", but HTTP/1.1 works in the same way as WebSocket for what pertains its usage of connections.
   If you are in a browser environment, browsers allow 6-8 HTTP connections to the same domain, and typically unlimited (or at least many more) WebSocket connections.
   So if you want to send, say, 10 large files, 6-8 of them will be uploaded via HTTP, but the remaining will be queued waiting for one of the HTTP connections to finish the previous upload.
   Meanwhile, you can use the WebSocket connection to send messages.
   In case of HTTP/2, browsers only open 1 connection, so you may use HTTP/2 streams for the uploads and a WebSocket over HTTP/2 stream for the messages, but they will all share the same HTTP/2 flow control window, potentially stalling each other.

All in all, WebSocket has not been designed for large uploads.

I would not be surprised if you hit WebSocket message size limits, as servers cannot allow clients to upload messages of arbitrary size (as it will blow up the server memory). The same is true for clients; browsers have typically small limits for the size of WebSocket messages that they receive, independently of whether HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 is used.

If you really need to upload large files, I think a solution where you upload via HTTP (which allow larger sizes, for example when using `multipart/form-data`), and keep small messaging via WebSocket is optimal.

The use of HTTP/2 *may* hit the HTTP/2 flow control window limit, but you have a limit in 6-8 connections in HTTP/1.1 too, so again you have to try and see *if* you hit any limit, and if you do, which limit it is in what case.

Using HTTP for uploads makes less likely that you hit WebSocket message size limits that are not known in advance and possibly different from client to client (browser to browser), and you don't want to implement your own splitting and merging of large uploads via WebSocket to respect those limits.